# JQuery does not work correctly everywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling, jquery-events

I am developing a small project on Asp.Net Core.
I have a piece of HTML code that is automatically generated:

```
@foreach(var item in list)
{
   <div class="some-code" id="@string.Concat(\"_col_\", @item.code)">*************</div>
   <div class="view-code" id=@item.code></code>
}
```

In fact, when this code runs, it looks like this in the browser elements:

```
  <div class="some-code" id="_col_t5]y56plK3">*************</div>
  <div class="view-code" id="t5]y56plK3"></code>

  <div class="some-code" id="_col_ye00c8dpo">*************</div>
  <div class="view-code" id="ye00c8dpo"></code>
  ...
```

In the picture it looks like this:

[image]

The logic is that when you click on the eye, the stars change to code and vice versa.
I did this using a small script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".view-code").on("click", function (e) {
            var mt = "*************"
            var id = "#_col_" + e.target.id;
            if ($(id).text() === mt) {
                $(id).text(e.target.id);
            } else {
                $(id).text(mt);
            }
        });
    })
```

So for several elements this works (the first 2) and on the rest, when you click on the eye, an error appears in the console and the code does not work.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #_col_1k]Xrm3rFs

Tell me why this is happening?
How to do it so everything works correctly?

Comment: The `]` character in the jQuery selector string has a special meaning and needs to be escaped: `\\]`

Comment: Or switch to `getElementById` without the leading `#` to avoid having to escape characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `]` character in the jQuery selector string has a special meaning and needs to be escaped: `\\]`

```
var id = "#_col_" + (e.target.id.replace(/]/g, '\\]');
```

***However*** a much better solution is to remove the generated `id` attributes entirely as they are an anti-pattern which makes your code more verbose, harder to maintain and just plain ugly. Instead, use DOM traversal to relate the elements to each other. As they are siblings this is as simple as using `prev()`, like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".view-code").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).prev('.some-code').text((i, t) => t == mt ? this.id : mt;
  });
})
```

```html
@foreach(var item in list) {
  <div class="some-code">*************</div>
  <div class="view-code" id="@item.code">
}
```